# Trouble converting user Inputs to a Date object

Tags: c#, date, input

I am trying to make use of the Date class in C#. I am new to coding, so go easy. I am taking user inputs, 1 at a time, month, then day. My goal is to be able to convert them to a string of the Date class that C# has built in. When I go to print my Date object, it doesn't return anything. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

I've tried to concatenate them into a string and it isn't working.

```
using System;
using Date_SOLUTION;
namespace Dates
{
    class Birthday
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDate today;
        int todayMonth;
        int todayDay;

        Console.WriteLine("What is today's month?");
        todayMonth = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("What is today's day?");
        todayDay = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        today = new MyDate(todayMonth,todayDay);
        Console.WriteLine(today);
}
}
}
```

My goal is to do Date math on this ultimately with more user input for their day of birth. But, my write state just returns Date_SOLUTION.MyDate.

Comment: `MyDate` is your custom class? What output do you expect from the code? Can you share the code of `MyDate` class?

Comment: please share your MyDate class, why didnt use DateTime class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int monthInput = 1;
int dayInput = 23;

try
{
    var myDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, monthInput, dayInput);
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    //monthInput is less than 1 or greater than 12.
    //- or -
    //dayInput is less than 1 or greater than the number of days in month.
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    throw;
}

Console.WriteLine($"{myDate}")
```

You can check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings for the standard format specifiers which you can then apply with (for example):

```
Console.WriteLine($"{myDate:yyyy-MM-dd}")
```